# MongoDB: Is it possible to index(unique) subarrays from documents in an isolated way?

Tags: mongodb

I recently encountered an issue, and I'd like to solve it. If anyone would give any suggestion I'll be grateful.

I have documents that represent "users" and each document has a subarray that is responsible to save some codes, they can be many for each user. The matter is, each user cannot have duplicate codes in its specific array, but at the same time, in this case, each document should be isolated, for example, being possible to have two or more identical codes but since they are from different documents(users).

**In short, the subarray("codes") cannot have individually duplicated codes(code), but that shouldn't interfere with other documents**

I could do that in the application part, but I think doing that guarantee directly on DB, it's safer.

Is it possible to create indexes for this specific situation?

Example of two documents representing their respective users:

```
{ // Document of user 1
    "_id" : "1", //user 1 and its codes
    "codes" : [
        {
            "code" : "1111",
            "description" : "code 1",
        },
        {
            "code" : "2222",
            "description" : "code 2",
        },
        {
            "code" : "3333",
            "description" : "code 3",
        }
    ]
},

{ // Document of user 2
    "_id" : "2", //user 2 and its codes
    "codes" : [
        {
            "code" : "1111",
            "description" : "code 1",
        },
        {
            "code" : "4444",
            "description" : "code 2",
        },
        {
            "code" : "2222",
            "description" : "code 3",
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/ to maintain uniqueness of code subdocuments. You will need to ensure that you always specify code fields in the same order (e.g. code, description).

Comment: Hello D.SM, thank you for answering. Yeah! I think it's a good alternative to solve my problem. I'm going to read a little about it and learning how to use this method. Thank you!